# How to launch an Android project from an Eclipse plugin programmatically?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

OK, I've started doing some Eclipse plugin development.

I've got my own custom icon in the toolbar.
When clicking the icon, I'd like to show the following screen to the user:

[image]

I have an `IProject` object of the Android project I'd like to launch.
Unfortunately, there's no simple `IProject.launch()` method...

What I've done so far is cloning the ADT source from here

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk
```

and started copying over all the necessary parts.

There must be an easier solution than this?
Can't I just hand over the launch of the project to Eclipse / ADT Plugin?

Comment: Why do you want to re-implement a functionality which is already available (with the "Run" button of the toolbar)?

Comment: Because my plugin is specific to one project. It changes its build configuration. Instead of opening a particular Java class and change some constants, you should just press the icon and it does all the stuff for you (including launching the project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to change some of the Java code directly before the user launches the project, you can go an easier route: Just implement an additional [project nature and an additional project builder](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html). Then add the nature and the builder to your specific projects. Make sure your new builder is before the other builders in the project builder order, like in the below screenshot

Everything else works like before. That way your plugin is like every other large plugin. E.g. the Android tools also do some magic first and then the normal Java builder is invoked, instead of re-implementing the Java stuff.

[image]